# Get DDL from existing databases SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I'm connecting to a postgresql database in AWS Redshift using SQLAlchemy to do some data processing, I need to extract the DDL information of each table in a particular Schema. I cant run any commands like `pg_dump --schema-only`. What will be the simplest way of extracting the DDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all tables with reflection system and print `CreateTable` construct of each table:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable

meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
for table in meta.sorted_tables:
    print(CreateTable(table).compile(engine))
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can do this without reflecting the database? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680802/column-does-not-exist-error-on-createtable